# Serialization system migration from Unreal Engine 4.19 to 4.26

Tags: c++, serialization, migration, deprecated, unreal-engine4

I'm working on migrating our client's game from unreal engine 4.19 to 4.26 and the only problem atm that I'm facing is their save system serialization. Here's how they serialize properties (which give me compilation errors):

```
FProperty** PropertyPtr = SaveGameProperties ? SaveGameProperties->Find(PropertyName) : nullptr;
FProperty* Property = PropertyPtr ? *PropertyPtr : nullptr;
if( Property )
{
    uint8* PropertyAddr = Property->ContainerPtrToValuePtr<uint8>(&Object);
    Property->SerializeItem(Ar, PropertyAddr);
}
else
{
    ensure(false);
    Ar.Seek(SkipOffset);
}
```

The line that is giving me a compilation error is `Property->SerializeItem(Ar, PropertyAddr);`. `Ar` is `FArchive&` btw. In 4.26 this function requires `FSlot`, which is a part of `FStructuredArchive` from what I've seen. I would like to know if there is a function that does the same thing but named differently or was moved to a different class/namespace because rewriting the entire SaveFile serialization would not be an ideal solution to this problem for me since the functionality of their extended save system is massive. I tried to look into release notes of the engine but couldn't find any information about this change and checking blobs (4.19->4.21 (where the change was introduced)) didn't give any insight since there was no `UE_DEPRECATED()` macro or something similar that would tell to change the system manually (looking through thousands of commits to find out when exactly this change was introduced is also not ideal) and I couldn't find anything on the forums either. Atm I'm using `Property->Serialize(Ar))` just to make the code compile (there are still a lot of other errors that I still have to fix, client has modified the engine as well, and a lot), but I'm not sure if it's the right solution to the problem since `SerializeItem(...)` is commented as part of `FProperty` interface whereas `Serialize(...)` is part of `UObject` interface and I don't know how exactly implementations of these functions have changed throughout the years in all of the children classes.

TLDR: Is there a way to replace this function call with functionally similar one that lets me serialize `FProperty` into `FArchive` the same way `SerializeItem(...)` did in 4.19? Thank you!

UPD: Sorry for the confusion with compilation errors part. What I meant is that `SerializeItem(...)` with a signature that includes `FArchive` does not exist, meaning I have to use something else.

Comment: "_which give me compilation errors_" - Include those errors in the question. If it's a lot, the 20-30 first lines may be enough.

Comment: Hey, yeah, sorry, had to be more specific with this I guess, basically compilation error is that function with this signature does not exist, meaning I have to find an alternative to it.

Comment: UE 4.27 contains this bugfix "_Fixed a problem in ArrayProperty's SerializeItem method when using a user-defined structured archive formatter, caused by a mismatch between the saving and loading branches when doing unversioned property serialization._" - Could that be related to the problem you have in 4.26?

Comment: @TedLyngmo sadly no, this already uses `FStructuredArchive::FSlot` for the function. My problem is that they changed the signature of the function from using `FArray` to `FSlot` and I don't know the best way to change this functionality without having to rewrite the entire save system since it will take too much time and Sony won't like if the old savefiles won't be compatible with the newer version of the game (it has PS4 version as well that we have to update).